# Haskell recursion with list of characters

Tags: string, list, haskell, recursion, character

I am studying Haskell and something came up where I am stuck on for few days.. so I am basically trying to recurse through the list of character (String) and once it reaches the end of the string, is there a way for me to recurse through the list from the head again?

Here is the code that works for recursing through the string once.

```
repeat2' :: [Char] -> Int -> [Char]
repeat2' [] _ = undefined
repeat2' (x:xs) 1 = [x]
repeat2' (x:xs) k
    | (k > 0) = x: repeat2' xs(k-1)
```

It works for

repeat2' "hey" 1 = "h"

repeat2' "hey" 2 = "he"

repeat2' "hey" 3 = "hey"

but once I try

repeat2' "hey" 4 = "hey*** Exception: Prelude.undefined"

As it is going to " repeat2' [] _ = undefined";

But I want it to print

repeat2' "hey" 4 = "heyh"

..So how I do i go back to the head of the string?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Am I right that this is for your homework? Because it seems that two of your fellow students might have asked for almost the same in the last few days ;) (and they two just registered here)

Comment: btw: it will be `undefined` for 4 because you told your function to be this with your very first case - also I give you the same hint as your fellow students: instead of dropping the `x` you might want to put it somewhere where further calls `repeat2'`might find it yet again ... further hint: you can use `x : ...` to prepend `x` to a list ... maybe you know something that can append it instead ...

Comment: Yeah it is haha except im not asking for an answer; just ideas and suggestions; Also im not quite getting what you are saying by "put it somewhere for further calls"..im pretty new to this language and not sure how you would do that.. im stll not sure how to pass the string to start from the head!

Comment: well at least one of the other was saying as much from the start (you see: usually we handle homework questions a bit different - as Luqui did) - for your question, I gave you another hint (but you should read the first maybe again): your problems with `"hey" 4` start when there is `"" 1` left - wouldn't it be nice if it where `"h" 1"` or even `"hey" 1` instead? (also see luqui's hint) - not looking at performance you can get to this if you will end up with `"eyh" 3` for your second recursive call - now how can you get the `h` from the start to the end of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me label the equations to refer to them later.

```
   repeat2' :: [Char] -> Int -> [Char]
1) repeat2' [] _ = undefined
2) repeat2' (x:xs) 1 = [x]
   repeat2' (x:xs) k
3)     | (k > 0) = x: repeat2' xs(k-1)
```

Let's trace the reduction of `repeat2' "hey" 4`.  First I will desugar the string into a list

```
repeat2' ['h', 'e', 'y'] 4
```

then the list into its cons cells

```
repeat2' ('h':'e':'y':[]) 4
```

Now we can begin

```
repeat2' ('h':'e':'y':[]) 4
-- equation 3 applies, x = 'h', xs = 'e':'y':[], k = 4
'h' : repeat2' ('e':'y':[]) 3
-- the first element of the result is known now, so it is printed by the repl
-- equation 3 applies ot the remainder
'h' : 'e' : repeat2' ('y':[]) 2
-- e is now known and printed
-- equation 3 applies
'h' : 'e' : 'y' : repeat2' [] 1 
-- y is known and printed
-- equation 1 applies
'h' : 'e' : 'y' : undefined
-- the repl errors out because of undefined
```

Thus explaining the output

```
"hey***Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

I hope this helps you understand.

One problem is that in order to cycle the list, you need to keep it around for recursive calls.  Note that by the time we have printed h, e, y the information to use next is no longer there.  You need to pass the list along untouched in addition to the one you are traversing.

Comment: Oh okay I see how its going; but yeah, i am stuck with passing the string again to go through the list... I've tried to do " (k /= 0) = x: repeat2' x:xs (k-1)  " where if there is an empty list with "k" that still has more character to go through, pass the string again to start from the head again except it still doesnt work..I just cant think of other way around..any more hint?

Comment: the easiest way you can pass the string again (or remember it) if you extend your function by one more parameter like: `repeat list (x:xs) k = ...` instead and then start your with `repeat "hey" "hey" 4`